# Watch-list screening classification method

Tags: classification, image-processing

I requires understanding and guide regarding how can I perform **watch-list screening in face recognition**.

I have read [this paper](http://www.polymtl.ca/litiv/doc/BashbaghietalICPR2014.pdf) and [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM0rTv1oTRAhVMq48KHTOZBiwQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.etsmtl.ca%2Fgetattachment%2FUnites-de-recherche%2FLIVIA%2FRecherche-et-innovation%2FPublications%2FPID3961327-(1).pdf&usg=AFQjCNG3WEXzCUwc-e-L-Fzh_X7KaualsQ&sig2=gpjuRAuuRWYkdIVYTczCUw) regarding watch-list screening face recognition. Based on 2nd paper, they use classification method as follow:

1. **Individual-specific decision thresholds** are selected using the score distribution obtained by matching gallery to non-target from UBM (**universal background model** that contain no image of individuals enrolled in system), at desired fpr **(false positive rate)** of the **cumulative PDF**.
2. Then during testing, *similarity scores between gallery and testing probe is calculated*. The score described the likelihood that the input probe correspond to template for individuals enrolled. Finally, decision is made by comparing the score and the individual-specific decision thresholds; *either to reject or to list the testing probe as likely individual*.

The question is, how I do those steps mathematically, and to code it in MATLAB?

Due to not enough knowledge about the method they used, I try to understand Speaker Verification using GMM by Reynolds. I have ask the question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720872/gaussian-mixture-model-for-face-verification).

Did I study the right topic?